# php get interface methods

Tags: php, class, interface

Is it possible to get the methods of an implemented interface?

For example, to return only function bar() that is in interface.

```
interface iFoo  
{   
  public function bar(); 
}

class Foo implements iFoo 
{   
  public function bar()
  { 
    ...
  }

  public function fooBar()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I know I can use class_implements to return the implemented interfaces, for example

```
print_r(class_implements('Foo'));

output:
Array ( [iFoo] => iFoo )
```

How do I get the methods of the implemented interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, implementing an interface means that you must define `ALL` methods in the child class, so what you are looking for is `ALL` of the methods from the interface(s).

**Single interface:**

```
$interface = class_implements('Foo');
$methods_implemented = get_class_methods(array_shift($interface));
var_dump($methods_implemented);
```

*Outputs:*

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

**Multiple Interfaces:**

```
$interfaces = class_implements('Foo');

$methods_implemented = array();
foreach($interfaces as $interface) {
    $methods_implemented = array_merge($methods_implemented, get_class_methods($interface));
}
var_dump($methods_implemented);
```

*Outputs:*

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  1 => string 'ubar' (length=4)
```

***Added interface `uFoo` to your example:***

```
interface uFoo {
    public function ubar();
}

interface iFoo  
{   
  public function bar(); 
}

class Foo implements iFoo, uFoo
{   
  public function bar()
  { 
  }

  public function fooBar()
  {
  }
  public function ubar(){}
}
```

Comment: good answer, but $interface[key($interface)]?? You can get that element by current($interface) or array_shift($interface)...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/reflection):

```
$iFooRef = new ReflectionClass('iFoo');
$methods = $iFooRef->getMethods();
print_r( $methods);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => bar
            [class] => iFoo
        )
)
```

If you want to call the methods defined in `iFoo` ref on a `Foo` object, you can do:

```
// Optional: Make sure Foo implements iFooRef
$fooRef = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
if( !$fooRef->implementsInterface('iFoo')) {
    throw new Exception("Foo must implement iFoo");
}

// Now invoke iFoo methods on Foo object
$foo = new Foo;
foreach( $iFooRef->getMethods() as $method) {
    call_user_func( array( $foo, $method->name));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a concrete implementation of an interface to know the methods a know interface implementation should have. The same `ReflectionClass` can do that:

```php
interface ExampleInterface
{
    public function foo();
    public function bar();
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass(ExampleInterface::class);

var_dump($reflection->isInterface());

$methods = $reflection->getMethods();

var_dump($methods[0]);
```

[Outputs:](https://3v4l.org/EqsYq)

```
bool(true)
object(ReflectionMethod)#2 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["class"]=>
  string(16) "ExampleInterface"
}
```

Also, unsurprisingly, `get_class_methods` would work just fine for interfaces:

```php
get_class_methods(ExampleInterface::class);
// returns ['foo', 'bar']
```