# How to enforce contract of type-hinted interface in PHP

Tags: php, interface, type-hinting

Let us imagine, we have following declaration of interface.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Sample;

interface A
{
    public function doSomething();
}
```

and class `B` that implements interface `A`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Sample;

class B implements A
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        //do something
    }

    public function doBOnlyThing()
    {
        //do thing that specific to B
    }  
}
```

Class `C` will depends on interface `A`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Sample;

class C
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function doManyThing()
    {
        //this call is OK
        $this->a->doSomething();

        //if $this->a is instance of B, 
        //PHP does allow following call
        //how to prevent this?
        $this->a->doBOnlyThing();            
    }  
}

...
(new C(new B()))->doManyThing();
```

If instance class `B` is passed to `C`, PHP does allow call to any public methods of B even though we typehint constructor to accept `A` interface only.

How can I prevent this with the help of PHP, instead of relying on any team members to adhere interface specification?

**Update** : Let us assume I can not make `doBOnlyThing()` method private as it is required in other place or it is part of third-party library that I can not change.

Comment: Can't you just set `B::doBOnlyThing` to `private function`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Let us say, I can not make it private because it is used somewhere else.

Comment: I can't understand. Interface can't be instantiated, you typehinted `A` interface in constructor and sent an object `B` implementing it (you can't send an `A` instance). What is wrong with this ? Seeing the upvotes I'm missing something.

Comment: @AymDev what I am looking is similar if you use interface in Java. If you have  property that is declared as an interface and try to call method  that is not part of the interface specification, compiler trigger compilation error.

Comment: If getting the *"only B things"* methods help: `$A = class_implements(($b = new B));
$A_methods = get_class_methods(array_shift($A));
echo '<pre>' . print_r(array_diff(get_class_methods($b), $A_methods), true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: @AymDev What I mean is, I want PHP to throws exception/error when there is call to methods that is not part of `A` interface inside `C` class (because C class is already declare it depends on `A` interface only).

Comment: I understood, yes. I tried but I don't have so much time to give a good solution. I thought using the code I pasted in my previous comment in a method that could be called before any method call and throwing an Exception if the `array_diff()` result isn't empty would be a solution. But implementing this is really hard as even the `__call()` method won't be called every time. Check this question if you want to give it a try: [How to auto call function in php for every other function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call)

Comment: using `__call()` and setting every methods as `protected` or `private` would work but you would still rely on your team members adherence.

Comment: @AymDev Thank you, really appreciate it, but I think, this should be PHP interpreter jobs to enforce the contract not application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it in PHP, as it doesn't prevent this type of method calling.

You can prevent it by using tools like [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) to detect method calls on parameters that aren't guaranteed to be there.

In almost any language there are features in the language that theoretically could be used, but the people in charge of a team of programmers choose to not allow those features to be how the team should be writing code.

Using static analysis tools, and other code quality tools are usually the best way to enforce these rules. Preferably on a pre-commit hook if you can set these up, otherwise in your automated build tools after a commit has been made.

Answer (score 1):

This proxy class will throw an exception when using other methods than specified interface:

```
class RestrictInterfaceProxy
{
    private $subject;
    private $interface;
    private $interface_methods;

    function __construct($subject, $interface)
    {
        $this->subject           = $subject;
        $this->interface         = $interface;
        $this->interface_methods = get_class_methods($interface);
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (in_array($method, $this->interface_methods)) {
            return call_user_func([$this->subject, $method], $args);
        } else {
            $class = get_class($this->subject);
            $interface = $this->interface;
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method <b>$method</b> from <b>$class</b> class is not part of <b>$interface</b> interface");
        }
    }
}
```

You should then change your `C` constructor:

```
class C
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        // Just send the interface name as 2nd parameter
        $this->a = new RestrictInterfaceProxy($a, 'A');
    }

    public function doManyThing()
    {
        $this->a->doSomething();
        $this->a->doBOnlyThing();
    }
}
```

#### Testing:

```
try {
    (new C(new B()))->doManyThing();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

> **Output:**
>   Method **doBOnlyThing** from **B** class is not part of **A** interface

**Previous answer:** I misunderstood OP's question. This class will throw an exception if a class has methods that none of the interface it implements has.
Use it as `$proxified = new InterfaceProxy(new Foo);`

```
class InterfaceProxy
{
    private $subject;

    /* In PHP 7.2+ you should typehint object
    see http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php */
    function __construct($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;

        // Here, check if $subject is complying
        $this->respectInterfaces();
    }

    // Calls your object methods
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (is_callable([$this->subject, $method])) {
            return call_user_func([$this->subject, $method], $args);
        } else {
            $class = get_class($this->subject);
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("No callable method $method at $class class");
        }
    }

    private function respectInterfaces() : void
    {
        // List all the implemented interfaces methods
        $interface_methods = [];
        foreach(class_implements($this->subject) as $interface) {
            $interface_methods = array_merge($interface_methods, get_class_methods($interface));
        }

        // Throw an Exception if the object has extra methods
        $class_methods = get_class_methods($this->subject);
        if (!empty(array_diff($class_methods, $interface_methods))) {
            throw new \Exception('Class <b>' . get_class($this->subject) . '</b> is not respecting its interfaces', 1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I took help on the following answers:

- [SO - php get interface methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572646/php-get-interface-methods#answer-17573071)
- [How to auto call function in php for every other function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/how-to-auto-call-function-in-php-for-every-other-function-call#answer-14086679)

Of course this solution is custom but as PHP won't solve this issue by itself I thought it would worth giving a try to build this myself.

Comment: I am not against class that declare public method that is not part of interface. I am trying to prevent any public method not part of interface to be called in other class which explicitly declared interface that it depends.

Comment: Oh I'm off-topic. Sorry OP. I'll edit my answer to mark it off-topic but will leave it as it may help someone else maybe

Comment: Hi @ZamronyP.Juhara, I updated my answer with a more accurate proxy, does it fullfill the requirements ?

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help my problem. Really appreciate it. Your proposed solution should work I guess. But 1) It introduces tight coupling with proxy. The reason we typehint interface is to avoid this kind of coupling, thus from my understanding, this defeat the purpose of interface, doesn't it?  2) You proxy class will only trigger exception if `dBOnlyThing` method is called. which is actually similar to duck-typing (as what we currently have). But again thank you very much. I guess I will try what @Danack proposed.

Comment: You are completely right, this is just an attempt. It has been fun to do indeed :-)